# Entity Framework 6 Add/Update - Error while edit and try to add edited entity as new one

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a model like below

```
public class XYZModel 
{
public string Id; // GUID, primary key;
public string Name;
public string AssociationId; // GUID, AllowNull;
}
```

what I am doing..
This is working fine

```
XYZModel abc = new XYZModel();
abc.Id = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid());
abc.Name = "ABC Name";
xyzDbContext.XYZModels.Add(abc);
xyzDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

What is my goal ? Get entity by id, Edit it, Change its primary key Id value, and add it as a new entry. but error occurred while adding.

```
XYZModel xyz = xyzDbContext.XYZModels.Find("xyzguid");

//modifying it
xyz.AssociationId = xyz.Id;
xyz.Id = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid());
xyz.Name = "New Name";

//trying to add it as new entry
xyzDbContext.XYZModels.Add(xyz);// Error 
xyzDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

It throw an error 
**The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that only if the `xyz` object is detached from `Context`.

Two ways to do that:

```
XYZModel xyz = xyzDbContext.XYZModels.Find("xyzguid");
xyzDbContext.Entry(xyz).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

Or using `AsNoTracking.FirstOrDefault`

```
XYZModel xyz = xyzDbContext.XYZModels.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id =="xyzguid");
```

Your code with first approach:

```
XYZModel xyz = xyzDbContext.XYZModels.Find("xyzguid");

xyzDbContext.Entry(xyz).State = EntityState.Detached;

//modifying it
xyz.AssociationId = xyz.Id;
xyz.Id = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid());
xyz.Name = "New Name";

//trying to add it as new entry
xyzDbContext.XYZModels.Add(xyz);// No Error 
xyzDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

**Note:**
You must use `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` annotation on `Id` property.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework tracks objects as you edit them. If you want a new row inserted into the database, create a new object in memory with the values you want and add that. A library like AutoMapper might come in handy here.